# How do i hide error notification messages in magento 2

Tags: php, magento

How to hide error notification message in Magento 2 (only error)?[see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4txWD.png)

Comment: Why hide the error message instead of figure out why it's there then prevent it from happen or catch it?

Comment: I'm learning m2 and I want to know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide errors, fix them!

It looks like you just need to enable guest checkout.

```
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options
```

The option should be in there

Comment: Yes. I know this ) But how do it in code. Ok, how hide notification success (one of more)

Comment: No idea,  but you could use XDebug to step through the code and see what magento does code wise